# Adding MPMediaItems to an MPMediaItemCollectino

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediaitem

I am making a music player app and I have an array of MPMediaItem objects which are representing songs in my music library. How do I put these objects in a music player and play the songs over the iPhone speaker?

I know to use an MPMusicPlayerController but I don't know how to add single MPMediaItems or an array of them to it

Comment: can you share your code so we can identify whats going wrong

Comment: There is nothing wrong... I would like to know how to take these objects and play them

Comment: edit your question and copy/past your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var myAvPlayer = AVPlayer()


if let itemUrl = mpMediaitem.assetURL {
   let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: itemUrl)
   myAvPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
   myAvPlayer.play()
}
```

Get `asset Url` from your `MPMediaItem` then using this url create `avplayeritem` object and assign to `avplayer` object.

Comment: how do i make myAvPlayer a global var though?

Comment: @JordanHeath just declare your `avplayer` variable in your `viewcontroller`, That's why i told you to show your code.

Comment: Ahh i just made it an optional '?'